# Which is faster in Excel, an if formula giving 1 or 0 instead of true/false or --?

Tags: excel

I've got a large spreadsheet that I'm trying to optimise as it has over 12,000 lines of data, with in excess of 28 columns. It currently takes a significant amount of time to execute and I'm therefore starting to pare it down.

As part of this I've started looking at the formulae. there are several which are IF formula which return 1,0 instead of True,False - Like this

```
=IF(AND(T2>365,J2>D5),1,0)
```

Would a Boolean result be quicker to run, and how would this be written? I'm aware you can put `--` in a formula, but I'm not sure of the exact specifics.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A boolean would most likely not yield better performance than integers, since the Excel formula engine is dynamically typed.

To significantly improve the performance of your spreadsheet, you should probably consider other options. Excel PowerPivot comes to mind, as it can easily handle millions of records with hundreds of calculations, and the DAX formula language is quite similar to Excel formulas, when calculations are being done on a row-by-row basis.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I've not used PowerPivot before so I'll look into that!